# Trying to provide operator that divides integer-type std::vector by constant

Tags: c++, vector

I want to multiply and divide all the elements of `std::vector` by constant in the same way as it is performed in C++ for ordinary types: at least the result should be integer when input vector has integer type and floating-point type otherwise.

I have found the code for multiplication based on `std::multiplies` and modified it with the replacement `std::divides`. As the result, the code works but not in the order I want it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// std::vector multiplication by constant
// http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77546
template <class T, class Q>
    std::vector <T> operator*(const Q c, const std::vector<T> &A) {

    std::vector <T> R(A.size());
    std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), R.begin(),
                 std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(),c));
    return R;
}

// My modification for division. There should be integer division
template <class T, class Q>
    std::vector <T> operator/(const std::vector<T> &A, const Q c) {

    std::vector <T> R(A.size());
    std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), R.begin(),
                 std::bind1st(std::divides<T>(),c));
    return R;
}



int main() {

    std::vector<size_t> vec;
    vec.push_back(100);

    int d = 50;

    std::vector<size_t> vec2 = d*vec;        
    std::vector<size_t> vec3 = vec/d;        
    std::cout<<vec[0]<<" "<<vec2[0]<<" "<<vec3[0]<<std::endl;

    // The result is:
    // 100 5000 0

    size_t check = vec[0]/50;
    std::cout<<check<<std::endl;
    // Here the result is 2

    // But

    std::vector<double> vec_d;        
    vec_d.push_back(100.0);        
    vec_d = vec_d/50;        
    std::cout<<vec_d[0]<<std::endl;

    // And here the result is 0.5

    return 0;
}
```

How can I write my operator correctly ? I thought that `std::bind1st` would call division by `c` for each element, but it does the opposite somehow.

EDIT: I understand that I can write a loop, but I want to do a lot of divisions for big numbers, so I wanted it to be faster...

Comment: Note that `std::transform` uses a loop internally, so there wouldn't be a performance benefit over a raw loop. (There might in fact be additional overhead for the function call and bind.)

Comment: @qxz Thanks! I see...

Comment: Seems you'd want `std::bind2nd(...)` or `std::bind(std::divides<T>(), _1, c)`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thank you very much! It worked!

Comment: @qcz: ... or `std::transform()` does a bit of "magic" and actually performs better than a loop. For example, the implementation may choose to vectorize the loop when it notices that it is used on a contigous sequence of integers. It is, however, rather unlikely to be slower than the loop.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thank you! Should I use any compiler options if I want it to enable this parallelization?

Comment: @Slowpoke: I'm not saying it certainly does these optimizations! There *could* be optimizations. Vectorization of reasonable loops is actually enabled for decent compilers with normal optimization (like `-O2` for gcc, clang, and icc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `std::transform` with C++11, I'd suggest making a lambda (see [this tutorial](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/c11-tutorial-lambda-expressions-the-nuts-and-bolts-of-functional-programming/)) instead of using `bind`:

```
std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), R.begin(), [c](T val) {
    return val / c;
});
```

In my opinion, lambdas are almost always more readable than `bind`ing, especially when (like in your case) you're not binding all of the function's parameters.

<strike>Although if you're worried about performance, a raw `for` loop might be slightly faster, as there's no overhead of the function call and creating the lambda object.</strike>

According to Dietmar Kühl:

> `std::transform()` may do a bit of "magic" and actually perform better than a loop. For example, the implementation may choose to vectorize the loop when it notices that it is used on a contiguous sequence of integers. It is, however, rather unlikely to be slower than the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto c_inverse= 1/c;
std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), R.begin(), [c_inverse](T val) {
    return val * c_inverse;
});
```

Similar to the other post, but it should be mentioned that rather than division, you will most likely see performance gains by multiplying by the inverse.

Comment: ... and what is `val`? Why are you capturing `c` but not using it?

Answer (score 1):

Why make it only for vectors? Here's a way to make more generic, to work with many types of containers:

```
template <class container, class Q>
container operator/(const container& A, const Q c) {
    container R;
    std::transform(std::cbegin(A), std::cend(A), std::back_inserter(R),
        [c](const auto& val) {return val / c; });
    return R;
}
```

Sure, it is expected to be a bit slower than with pre-allocation for a vector, since the `back_inserter` will allocate dynamically as it grows, but well, sometimes it might be appropriate to trade speed for genericity.

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm limited to vectors in my program that may be a good point for someone